# How do I transform multiple values in a dataframe, associated in a 1 to many a relation to two other variables, to a single row elegantly?

Tags: r, dataframe

Data:

```
names real_name type
a         A      AA
aa        A      AA
a-        A      AA
b         B      BB
bbb       B      BB
...
```

Wanted result:

```
names         real_name type
{a, aa, a-}      A       AA
{b, bbb}         B       BB
```

I want to get rid of the redundancy and be able to traverse through names. I have almost managed to get to the wanted results with loops and `tidyr`.
What is the elegant way to get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df <- tibble(names = c("a", "aa", "a-", "b", "bbb"), 
       real_name = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 2)),
       type = c(rep("AA", 3), rep("BB", 2)))
```

You can try `nest` if you want a list-col

```
df %>% nest(names)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  real_name  type             data
      <chr> <chr>           <list>
1         A    AA <tibble [3 x 1]>
2         B    BB <tibble [2 x 1]>
```

Or `summarize` if you really want a string with all the names in it:

```
df %>% group_by(real_name, type) %>% summarize(x = paste(names, collapse = ", "))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   real_name [?]
  real_name  type         x
      <chr> <chr>     <chr>
1         A    AA a, aa, a-
2         B    BB    b, bbb
```

Comment: Thanks. Was looking for redundancy, so summarize did it. Btw, you better use "summarise" so you won't get confused with "summarise_each" which is only spelled with an s.